# Show/Hide Image in HTML table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have a simple table that shows some workflow runs. The 'Status' property can display 'Failed' or 'Succeeded'. I want the 'Succeeded.png' to show on all the succeeded runs and the 'Failed.png' for all the failed runs.

How can I do this?

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="myToolTip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="" data-placement="left">
                <td>                  
                    <span><img src="~/Content/Img/Failed.png" id="failedLogo"/></span>
                    <span><img src="~/Content/Img/Succeeded.png" id="successLogo" /></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status).
                </td>
  <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CorrelationId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputUri)">Input Uri</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputContentSize)@{WriteLiteral("Kb");}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OutputUri)">Output Uri</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OutputContentSize)@{WriteLiteral("Kb");}
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Error)
               </td>

            </tr>
                        }

    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<img src='@(item.Status=="Succeeded" ? "Succeeded.png" : "Failed.png")' alt='status' />
```

Comment: Thanks! I can now see that he images are sorted to the correct status but unfortunately they do not display in the browser. "Can not load image" if I inspect the element.

Comment: You just need to use the full path = `"~/Content/Img/Succeeded.png"` etc

Answer (score 0):

First convert your column result to an image and then display the image where applicable. For example:

```
if $result = "1" then
    $image = "success.gif"
else
    $image = "fail.gif"
end if
```

Then you can use **$image** as the result to display in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Added an if-statement instead and it worked!

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It's the OP telling how they solved the issue.